# Is Find My iPhone Lost Mode not permanent?

Tags: find-my-iphone

My iPhone was stolen 3 months ago, it was in lost mode and every time I open Find My iPhone application, it appears offline. But today I see in Find My iPhone app my device doesn't appear anymore. It has just disappeared from my the Find My iPhone app.

Could it be the lost mode feature of Find My iPhone is no longer functioning because the device has spent too long in offline mode? Is the lost mode feature not permanent?

Comment: My MacBook's been "Locked" via iCloud since it was stolen a year ago. I have no reason to believe that'll change. Though, in the case of a laptop, they probably just reformatted the drive and moved on.